# How to make and apply standards for UI development?

Tags: user-interface, standards

I work in a small and young team of developers and we have problems that we are not sure how to solve.

On previous projects every developer have been working on tasks that were based on use cases. So, upon setting the system architecture, each team member worked on user interface and business logic of tasks assigned to him.

This kind of organization gave us the problems with UI. Each developer had his own logic about how UI should look like, where buttons should be, etc etc... and even if we've had one css designer a lot of refactoring had to be done in order to make web site to look compactly.

- How do you deal with this issue?
- Do you split tasks based on layer, not on whole use case?
- Do you use some technical solution to achieve this or is it just written standard that every developer need to follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution might be to create sketches of all screens of your application, have them reviewed by an ergonomy-expert to correct the biggest mistakes, and, only then, give them to your developpers.

This way, they would know how the screens they are developping should look like -- there will still be a couple of differences in the end, but those should not be "big differences", and should be eaiser to fix.

And this would mean not each developper has to imagine what the perfect screen would look like : each one of those would be coherent with the others.

Comment: I really like your answer, sounds like a proper way to do it. Maybe I would just add (somewhere in the process) the end user acceptance of the UI.

Comment: Yes, going through some end-user acceptance test might be a good idea too, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone has their own style and it would be difficult and a waste of time to define a standard that would get everyone to draw the UI in a consistent manner. Instead, elect your best UI designer to do what he does best and design the UI for the whole system. Funneling all UI changes through the designer would be difficult so just let your developers "mess it up" as they implement new use cases and just have your designer clean it up before the release. It shouldn't be hard for him/her to rearrange the existing forms and bring some consistency back to the UI.

Comment: This is probably easiest to apply. I would just add the end user acceptance of the initial design before giving it to developers. Maybe developers will "mess it up" less if they have the clue how the interface should look like. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I've found this [12 Standard Screen Patterns](http://designingwebinterfaces.com/designing-web-interfaces-12-screen-patterns) article very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Adopt the tried and tested MVC system, let the view be decoupled from the business logic. Then ask a UI designer to produce sketches and work to that. UI's are something best done top-down from my experience. The user gets an overall view before being presented with all the details, defining and capturing this hierarchy makes good UI's. Coding of business logic is done as you mentioned on a use-case basis, mostly bottom-up and this is where the code falls out of sync with the UI.

Comment: Ok, we are using the MVC system, but sometimes even the controllers logic has to be changed and that demands more work than just altering the view. But indeed it simplifies the process of adapting the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Designate one person (preferably someone with graphic design experience, even if they're not really a programmer) and give them the authority to make cosmetic changes to all forms, pages and controls at any time, and have them be responsible for the overall look and feel of the application.

As far as metrics go, keep track of how much time this one person has to spend "fixing" each programmer's work, and make sure the programmers are aware of these numbers.  The idea is to encourage them to make their stuff look like it should from the beginning, but also not to do weird things based on what they think stuff should look like.  I've had to spend more time undoing my coworkers' bizarre design choices than anything else.

Don't be afraid to have outside sources review the design work of each programmer.  It's very common for programmers to 1) produce horrible-looking UIs, and 2) believe the UIs look fantastic.  You should do what the Army does with boot camp:  break them down completely right from the start, so that you can build them back up again the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem with creating your own written standard is that while well meaning, there could be mistakes or better ways to do things than what's been standardized. For example, where I work, the standardized cancel button does nothing when you click on it (it's been wired to Reset).

Instead, I recommend choosing existing standards, such as [The Macintosh Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIntro/XHIGIntro.html) or [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx). Even if the standard is wrong, it's rarely profitable to deviate from widely established conventions.

Then pick up some good books for the developers, such as "Designing Interfaces: Patterns for Effective Interaction Design". Good user interface design is partially a matter of good taste, and while not every developer will be interested in the subject, it's in your best interest to help them improve.

Next, empower your QA team to file bugs when the interface for one product is inconsistent with another. The developer can then either standardize or justify the deviation if he has a reason. We do this; it works pretty well.

Lastly, go over your existing products and get a consensus on how their interfaces should be unified. Bring in (and keep) a usability expert if you can. I've seen good ones do amazing work.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no clear solution for how to deal with UI problems. There are however several approaches one can take to combat the problem of having things become too complicated:

- Use cases are usually cross disciplinary in nature, thus the responsibility to get a use case done should be split between the people who can implement it properly. Programmer and designer type of people need to cooperate.
- Everyone in the team needs to keep in mind [seperation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), i.e. things that can be seperated must be kept that way preferably as early as possible. There are so many ways to do this: e.g. apply MVC pattern in your project (which is a very wide way to put it). Presentation and logic should be seperate so that changes in one layer should not affect the other.
- Someone needs to be responsible for the overall UI design so it is consistent throughout the application. Preferably someone who is both a graphic designer and has some insight in usability. UI design is something that needs to be planned along with the use cases and revised constantly as development goes on. Consistent UI is very important and developers need to be on board on it.